# Should every title have something specifically Jewish in it?

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles

In [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1544251#1544251), Robert Cartaino indicated that a few questions looked ambiguous and not "findable." He clarified:

> Titles are important. If I saw a Tweet that said "Why don't we bow 'correctly' any more", it makes no sense. It's much clearer to say "Why don't Jews bow correctly anymore" or whatever makes the title clearer.

It seems to me that what he's driving at is that every question title ought to contain some clue that the context of the question is Jewish, if only so they pop out for potentially-interested people who scan lists of titles, for example on Twitter. Most of our titles already comply with this guideline. Shall we make it a requirement from now on?

(A possible exception to this rule would be questions that could be meaningful/interesting outside the specifically Jewish context, such as [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8989/what-is-the-best-way-to-break-a-fast). The goal, I suppose, is to make sure that each title looks meaningful/interesting on its own.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clarify… The questions

**Why do we double (or triple) wrap food?**
**Why don't we bow "correctly" anymore?**

were clarified to add a bit of context:

**What's the halachic advantage of double (or triple) wrapping food?**
**Why don't we bow "correctly" during tefillah anymore?**

The revisions made those question clearer and less ambiguous.

The vast majority of questions on this site are just fine. But anytime you see an opportunity to improve a question (or an answer), you should take advantage of the wiki-nature of this site to improve the content.

Titles are particularly important because your home page is the design of your site. When a potential user comes across your content in a Google search or a Twitter feed, the title is all they have to go by. Question titles should be as clear and intriguing as possible.

I don't know if this needs to be a specific "requirement" codified somewhere. You have to use your best judgement and make the most of the opportunity you have to attract new users. That's just good community management.

Comment: Requirement or not, if this is a principle we should keep in mind, it makes sense for it to be exposed to the whole community, here.